# how to find root of a directed acyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm, directed-graph

I need a method to find root of a directed acyclic graph.I am using boolean adjancency matix to represent graph in java.so please suggest.Also graph is unweighted graph

Answer (score 8):

Just find the node where indegree is 0. For below algorithm to work we assume that none of nodes in graph are isolated.

```
int indegree[N]={0};

for(i=0;i<n;++i){
  for(j=0;j<n;++j){
      if(graph[i][j]==1){ //assuming edge from i to j
           indegree[j]++;
      }
  }
}
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
   if(indegree[i]==0) add i to roots;
}
```

Comment: What could be Big-O time comlexiti of this solution?

Comment: Possible optimisation if search only for root not number of in-degrees: `if (array_sum($graph[$i])) { $roots[] = $i; };`. If weights are only 1: `$indegree[$i] = array_sum($graph[$i]);`.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for nodes with no in-edges.  If the adjacency matrix is encoded so that entry (i,j) contains a 1 if and only if there is an edge from i to j, then for node K to be a root, there must be no edges of the form i->K, therefore no 1's in entries of the form (i, K).  So you are looking for columns K with all zeros. Each such column is a root.

In pseudocode,

```
roots = {}
for k in 1 to N
  for i in 1 to N
    if adjacencies[i, k] > 0
      continue with next k value
  add k to roots
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in linear time. It is basically doing DFS over the graph with all the edges reversed.

- Pick up any vertex in the given  graph **G**
- Check if the vertex has **in-degree** equal to **0**. If it does we have found a vertex which is root of the graph.
- If not then, mark the current vertex **v** as **visited** and  repeat the same process over all the unvisited parents of **v**.

This will fetch all the required vertices with in-degree equal to zero or roots of a DAG.